# Does instance of runnable class gets destroyed when Thread exits in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

If have a class implementing runnable class with following code:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public Thread t;
    // Other variables;

    public MyRunnable() {
        t = new Thread(this, "MyRunnable Thread");
        // Initialise other variables.
    }

    public void run() {
       //Do something.
    }
}
```

And i am making an instance of the above class in the following way:

```
public class MyFunc () {
  satic void main (String ards[]) {
     MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable();
     mr.t.start();


     while (true) {
         Thread.sleep(10000);
         if (!mr.isAlive()) {
              //Execute mr again.
              // How to do it ?
         }
     }
  }
}
```

How should i do it?

I have two ways in mind, but not sure which one is correct:

**1.**  mr.t.start();

**2.**  MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable();
        mr.t.start();

Should i make a new instance of mr?

Or should i work with the existing instance or mr ?

Comment: What you get when you try executing the code ?

Comment: I haven't yet executed it. I am currently writing the code. This is just one part of the whole project that I am making.

Comment: But your code has multiple compile errors !

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: How should i do it ? Should i make a new instance ? Or should i just start the thread again, using the already made instance..

Comment: You should give a properly written Runnable to a TimerTask.  This is exactly why you should research more and write less.

Answer (score 3):

Remove reference to `Thread` from `MyRunnable`.

Starting thread idiom in Java looks like this

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start()
```

Normal rules of garbage collection applies to cleaning runnables. If no object references runnable it may be garbage collected.

Comment: So if i do something like the following, will it be correct then:  MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable(); Thread t = new Thread(mr); t.start();  AND then when i check like if (!t.isAlive) { t = new Thread(mr); t.start() }

Comment: I basically don't want to make a new instance of the MyRunnable class. Is it possible using the above mentioned way ?

Comment: if your Runnable retains any state, then reusing it becomes slightly more complicated - you'd need to reinitialize its persistent state.

Answer (score 1):

There are several idioms around writing multi-threaded code in Java, see the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). Keep it simple and separate:

```
public class YourTask implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do something
   }
}
```

A minimal example application:

```
public class YourApp {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final YourTask yourTask = new YourTask();
    final Thread thread = new Thread(yourTask);
    thread.start();

    thread.join();
   }
}
```

Be careful with concurrency - you shouldn't use this code in production until you have a proper understanding, for example by reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this code.

Your `Runnable` shouldn't have a `Thread` member, public or private.  I'd recommend removing it.  Think simple: separation of concerns.  This is what your Runnable ought to look like:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       //Do something.
    }
}
```

That's it.  Let other classes that know how to run things handle that part.

You're better off looking at the newer concurrent package classes, like `Executor`.

You shouldn't be trying to do a lot of multi-threaded programming unless you've read Brian Goetz' ["Java Concurrency In Practice"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004V9OA84) and understood it thoroughly.  You're less likely to run into trouble.

Comment: Can u please tell why is this not good style of Java ? And what should tne the way ? P.S.: I got this type of style from this link : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm

Answer (score 0):

Runnable has the method run(), so you do not need separate Thread inside that.And nothing gets destroyed unless if you go out from the context of your variable (object) definition and you loose the reference.

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_runnable_construction.shtml